# A string must start with numbers 0-9 and end with numbers[0-9]

Tags: php, regex, string

I am validating a string using **preg_match()** function.

Bellow you could see my code, it works fine ,it checks if a string starts with Numbers,and ends with 80.

```
<?php
$wrd=$_POST["txt"];
if(preg_match("/^[0-9)]{3}80\z/",$wrd))
{echo "this string is ok";}
else {echo "false";}?>
```

**Edited**

**Now what I want to achive is:** A string must start with numbers 0-9 and end with numbers 0-9.and length of the string must be at least 3. 
Any help is appriciated! Thanks

Comment: Any string that ends in any amount of numbers 0-9? Be a little more specific please.

Comment: You mean this: `preg_match("/^\d.*?\d$/", $wrd)` ?

Comment: just add at the end of your regex `[0-9]&` or if it is more than one `[0-9]+&` or a specific quantity `[0-9]{2}&`

Comment: Why you added `)` inside the first character class?

Comment: @Amit why a late edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any string that ends in any amount of numbers 0-9:

```
'/.*[0-9]+$/'
```

Any string that ends in just 0-9

```
'/.*[0-9]$/'
```

Your existing match that ends in any amount of number (rather than 80):

```
'/^[0-9]{3}.*[0-9]+$/'
```

Your existing regex also contains a `)` in your character set which will match 0-9 or a bracket at the start of your string - [Example](http://regexr.com/3a8r2).

**Edit:**

For your edited question - "A string must start with numbers 0-9 and end with numbers 0-9.and length of the string must be 3." - Try:

```
/^\d.\d$/
```

[Example here](http://regexr.com/3a8r8)

Comment: You don't need the `+` version. If it ends with 1 number, then it also ends with at least 1 number.

Answer (score 3):

The following regex will match a string that begins with a number 0-9, ends with a number 0-9, and is exactly 3 characters long:

```
^[0-9].[0-9]$
```

This will also work:

```
^\d.\d$
```

[Please see Regex Demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/fM6wL9/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
^\d.+\d$
```

This makes sure that the expression starts with number and you can have any number of characters in between and it ends with a number.